# How to deal with duplicate data that complement each other in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas and I'm trying to delete all duplicates that have type *object*. But, the problem that I'm facing is that some duplicate data complement each other. For example, having the following dataframe:

```
print (df)
   name   ID   location
0   A     NaN     LA
1   A     30      NaN
2   B     NaN     NaN
3   B     NaN      NY
4   B     20      NY
5   D     15      TX
6   D     15      NaN
```

As you can see, most of them are needed, but at the same time considered as duplicate. How can I solve this problem when facing this type of scenario?

The outcome that I need is the following:

```
print (df)
   name   ID   location
0   A     30     LA
1   B     20     NY
2   D     15     TX
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It's difficult to tell what your desired outcome is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the question and added the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Name'],as_index=False).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df.groupby('name').first(dropna=True)
```

it returns:

```
name  ID    location              
A     30.0       LA
B     20.0       NY
D     15.0       TX
```

Comment: I did not get this error, I am not sure how it arises. How does your actual df looks like?  Though you may try 'skipna=True' instead.